# How can we make the request should only get timed out, if there is no response in specified time interval

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I am using jquery.ajax with timeout 90sec to call an Asp.net webAPI get method.
Request is timed out at 90sec even in between data is retrieving. 
How can we make the request should only get timed out, if there is no response in specified time interval. currently irrespective to response, request is getting timeout at specified time from request start.

Comment: Your request is taking 1 and a half minutes, and it's still downloading data?!? I would fix that problem first before messing with timeouts.

Comment: haha @Rory. Thanks for your response. its a bulk json data.
And there are multiple layers in between webAPI and database.

Comment: I think it is only a _if problem_ in your timeout. Basically, after 90 sec, check _if has a response_ and if yes do the call to the asp method... Well, as I'm not seeing any code here, I imagine that you can start a _var hasResponse = false_ and when receive response set _hasResponse = true_ ... If you get this, then will be easy to check after 90secs if need to call or not the asp method.